# Join MS Access Queries to get Gross Pay Breakdown by Week

Tags: ms-access

Good Day All,
I have 5 queries that sums an employee pay by week. For example:-

`qryWK1 - sums pay from qryPayDetails between First of the Month to First Monday of the Month`

`qryWK2 - sums pay from qryPayDetails between First Monday of the Month + 1 to Second Monday of the Month`

`qryWK3 - sums pay from qryPayDetails between Second Monday of the Month + 1 to Third Monday of the Month`

`......`

`qryWK5 - sums pay from qryPayDetails between Forth Monday of the Month + 1 to End of the Month`

I am have problems joining the queries to show the data as follows

EMPID___MONTH____WK1_____WK2_____WK3_____WK4_____WK5
1________1/2019_____800_______0_______200______500_______0
2________6/2019_____1000_____100______300_______0_______600
1________6/2019_____800_______0_______200______500_______0

I'm trying to get a year summary of each employee.

I've tried this:

`SELECT tblPayroll.EMPID, Format([WorkDay],"m/yyyy") AS GBM, qryYTDWK1.SumOfGross, qryYTDWK2.SumOfGross, qryYTDWK3.SumOfGross, qryYTDWK4.SumOfGross, qryYTDWK5.SumOfGross
FROM ((((tblPayroll LEFT JOIN qryYTDWK1 ON tblPayroll.EMPID = qryYTDWK1.EMPID) LEFT JOIN qryYTDWK2 ON tblPayroll.EMPID = qryYTDWK2.EMPID) LEFT JOIN qryYTDWK3 ON tblPayroll.EMPID = qryYTDWK3.EMPID) LEFT JOIN qryYTDWK4 ON tblPayroll.EMPID = qryYTDWK4.EMPID) LEFT JOIN qryYTDWK5 ON tblPayroll.EMPID = qryYTDWK5.EMPID
GROUP BY tblPayroll.EMPID, Format([WorkDay],"m/yyyy"), qryYTDWK1.SumOfGross, qryYTDWK2.SumOfGross, qryYTDWK3.SumOfGross, qryYTDWK4.SumOfGross, qryYTDWK5.SumOfGross;`

but I am getting duplicates.

Comment: Should be able to calculate a week number for each record then use a CROSSTAB to pivot data. Edit question to show sample raw data.

Comment: Why 5 queries? Doesn't make sense, you only need one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would like to give credit to RJD at utteraccess.com for solving this problem using a Union Query

https://www.utteraccess.com/forum/index.php?showtopic=2054744&st=0&gopid=2727412&#entry2727412

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you want Monday as first day of week. Also, you want days of partial week included with the month they fall in. This means weeks are not all the same length.

Function to return week number of month with Monday as first day of week:

```
Public Function fCalcWeekOfMonth(dteDate As Date) As Byte
fCalcWeekOfMonth = DatePart("ww", dteDate, vbMonday) - _
                   DatePart("ww", DateSerial(Year(dteDate), Month(dteDate), 1), vbMonday) + 1
End Function
```

Call that function in a query that extracts year and month as well as week number from date field and pivot with CROSSTAB. Example:

```
TRANSFORM Sum(Rates.Rate) AS SumOfRate
SELECT Rates.Pos, Year([EffDate]) AS Yr, Month([EffDate]) AS Mo
FROM Rates
GROUP BY Rates.Pos, Year([EffDate]), Month([EffDate])
PIVOT fCalcWeekOfMonth([EffDate]) In (1,2,3,4,5);
```